# GDB connection timeout when attaching to QEMU

Tags: gdb, qemu, riscv, bare-metal

I am trying to attach GDB to QEMU for my bare-metal project on RISC-V. However, it is unable to connect. My host is a Ubuntu by WSL on a Windows machine. I am using the firmware supplied by openSBI to launch my custom "bootloader" (boot.bin).

I run QEMU (in Ubuntu WSL):

`qemu-system-riscv64.exe --machine virt -m 256 -bios ./opensbi/build/platform/generic/firmware/fw_jump.bin -kernel ./boot.bin --nographic -s -S`

Then I open a new command line (new Ubuntu WSL window) and start GDB:

`riscv-gnu/bin/riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb`

and specify a target:
`target remote localhost:1234`

After a few seconds this gives me the error: localhost:1234: Connection timed out.

Has anyone else had this issue, would be greatful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually WSL has an IP address in a different network so if you want to make a connection between WSL and Windows you need to provide correct IP and not just `localhost`.

[image]

Check `ipconfig` under Windows and in `gdb` provide IP of the correct network.

In my case Windows has a local address of `192.168.1.24` and WSL has `172.190.0.1`. So to connect gdb from WSL to qemu running on Windows I need to type `target remote 192.168.1.24`.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear, both GDB and QEMU is running on WSL (Ubuntu) but on separate windows. Will edit to clarify

Comment: why then you run qemu as Windows executable? This is Windows' version `qemu-system-riscv64.exe`. Can't you install Linux version and use that?

Comment: I do not know why I did, that was a stupid mistake. GDB connects now. Thank you for uncovering this simple mistake!